# powerdns with mysql backend : Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user

Tags: debian, powerdns

I have a problem with my gmysql and Powerdns on Debian Squeeze , I keep getting this error :

```
Sep 21 16:30:35 lucas pdns[24429]: gmysql Connection failed: Unable to connect to database: Access denied for user 'power_admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Sep 21 16:30:35 lucas pdns[24429]: Caught an exception instantiating a backend, cleaning up
```

However I tried logging in with to mysql cli with the user and password provided in the config file and it logs in normally.

What am I not seeing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your settings in powerdns, one of the config files has a separate entry for user and password to log into your mysql backend.

I think your mistake might lie there!

Answer (score 1):

Well if PowerDNS says it is unable to connect that's usually just it.
Did you grant it permission in mysql and issue "flush privileges;"?

Do you have this for all backend instances (default with debian is 3 i think) or does the error just occur occasionally?

Answer (score 0):

Is your password complex?  I have found [reference to passwords containing the # character causing this bug.](http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-31087.html)

Try an alphanumeric, but strong, password.

Comment: nope it does not contain special characters anymore, I tried that :)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in config file.
/etc/pdns/pdns.conf

```
gmysql-password=
```

After restarting the server, the password returned to the old one. I assume that the data was kept by the RAM or some cache in the raid. A reboot triggered the problem.